# Regex is not working for some cases - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a number of string patterns from which I filter out my data and insert it into a database. Now, I have to handle strings that my old regex is not able to match correctly.

This is my regex:

```
$re = "/(?:Expiration Fee: )?(\d+)\s+((?:[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+\s+)*)(?:\(([a-zA-Z]+)\)\s+)?(?:>([0-9.]+)\s+)?(?:(\d+-\d+)\s+)?(?:\((\d{1,2}(?::\d{2})?[AP]M)\)\s+)?(?:@\s+([\d.]+))/";
```

My complete code:

```
$re = "/(?:Expiration Fee: )?(\d+)\s+((?:[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+\s+)*)(?:\(([a-zA-Z]+)\)\s+)?(?:>([0-9.]+)\s+)?(?:(\d+-\d+)\s+)?(?:\((\d{1,2}(?::\d{2})?[AP]M)\)\s+)?(?:@\s+([\d.]+))/";

        $strs = array("Expiration Fee: 10 LONG AUD/USD >.8189 (9:50AM) @ 90.5","10 Wall St 30 (Mar) >17900 (4:15PM) @ 69.5","2 AUD/USD >.8114 (11:35AM) @ 97.5","Expiration Fee: 1 SHORT AUD/USD >.8114 (11:35AM) @ 87","2 Wall St 30 (Mar) 18000-18100 (12PM) @ 18023","2 LONG US Tech 100 (Mar) >4284 (1:15PM) @ 56.5","1 EUR/USD >1.2180 (3PM) @ 41.5","Expiration Fee: 1 SHORT AUD/USD >.8114 (11:35AM) @ 87","Expiration Fee: 1 LONG GBP/USD >1.5090 (8:55PM) @ 95.5","Expiration Fee: 2 SHORT US 500 (Mar) >2037.7 (10AM) @ 5.5","Expiration Fee: 1 SHORT EUR/USD >1.1582 (2:20PM) @ 11.5","6 SHORT GBP/USD >1.5200 (3:10PM) @ 22.3333","Expiration Fee: 1 SHORT GBP/USD >1.5085 (8PM) @ 17.5","Expiration Fee: 1 SHORT EUR/GBP >.7340 (3PM) @ 33.25","2 Wall St 30 (Mar) 18000-18100 (12PM) @ 18023","Expiration Fee: 5 LONG US Tech 100 (Mar) 4190-4390 (4:15PM) @ 4291","2 LONG Wall St 30 (Mar) >18000 (1:15PM) @ 53.5","1 AUD/USD .7570-.7670 (2PM) @ 0.7626","1 US 500 (Jun) 2075.0-2085.0","1 US 500 (Jun) 2075.0-2085.0 (1PM) @ 2079","1 US 500 (Jun) 2075.0-2085.0 (1PM) @ 2079","
1 AUD/USD .7570-.7670 (2PM) @ 0.7626","2 AUD/USD .8020-.8220 (11PM) @ 0.8118");
foreach ($strs as $subject) {
    echo "======<br />\n$subject<br />\n";
    if (preg_match($re, $subject, $m))
        for ($i=1; $i<count($m); $i++)
            if ($m[$i]) echo "$m[$i]<br />\n";
}
```

The string patterns which are not working for me:

```
1 AUD/USD .7570-.7670 (2PM) @ 0.7626

1 US 500 (Jun) 2075.0-2085.0

1 US 500 (Jun) 2075.0-2085.0 (1PM) @ 2079

1 AUD/USD .7570-.7670 (2PM) @ 0.7626

2 AUD/USD .8020-.8220 (11PM) @ 0.8118
```

Online screenshot for demonstration:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the regex that will match all of the cases:

```
(?:Expiration Fee: )?(\d+)\s+((?:[a-zA-Z\d\/]+\s+)*)(?:\(([a-zA-Z]+)\)\s+)?(?:>([0-9.]+)\s+)?(?:([\d.]+-[\d.]+)\s*)?(?:\((\d{1,2}(?::\d{2})?[AP]M)\)\s+)?(?:@\s+([\d.]+))?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/1)

A shortened version to be used with `i` option and with unified digit matching:

```
(?:Expiration Fee: )?(\d+)\s+((?:[a-z\d\/]+\s+)*)(?:\(([a-z]+)\)\s+)?(?:>([\d.]+)\s+)?(?:([\d.]+-[\d.]+)\s*)?(?:\((\d{1,2}(?::\d{2})?[AP]M)\)\s+)?(?:@\s+([\d.]+))?
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/2)

Comment: There was no "error". The main problem was that `\s` was used with `+` quantifier in `(?:(\d+-\d+)\s+)?`, and I also added `.` to the character class to match `1.22-2.33`. With the quantifier changed to `*`, we can capture the case I mentioned in vks's post.

Comment: thank you very much its working for me. :) PS: how to master regex? any good guide and solid guide please you can share?

Comment: I think you need to use VERBOSE regexes if you plan to maintain them. Yours is so long it takes minutes to read it. When you use `x` option, you can indent, use comments, newlines in the pattern, and you will easily see what is following what and the hierarchy will be visible. The best way (IMHO) to master PHP regex is to read http://www.regular-expressions.info/, http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php, refer to http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/. As an alternative, follow `regex` tag in StackOverflow - you will find lots of interesting posts and solutions.

Comment: thank you very much please. it really helped me. I want to master PHP regex from scratch to ninga so I put it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:Expiration Fee: )?(\d+)\s+((?:[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+\s+)*)(?:\(([a-zA-Z]+)\)\s+)?(?:>([0-9.]+)\s+)?(?:([.\d]+-[.\d]+)\s*)?(?:\((\d{1,2}(?::\d{2})?[AP]M)\)\s+)?(?:@\s+([\d.]+))?$

                                                                                                     ^^    ^^     ^^                                                      ^^
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/1

Also use `anchors` to make sure you dont make partial matches.

Comment: Yours does not match `1 US 500 (Jun) 2075.0-2085.0`.

Comment: Will this work for all string patterns? It seems it is not working for all cases.

Comment: @vks yes it doesn't match `1 US 500 (Jun) 2075.0-2085.0`

Comment: @MuhammadMohsin check the changes too...its marked by `^^`

Comment: @vks what do you mean by `^^` ? it is identifying problem in my regex? correct? and thank you its working now for all cases. :)

Comment: Thank you very much please.. ;) it is working fine. PS: how to master regex? any good guide and solid guide please you can share?